# TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple, Occurs on TextClip() call from MoviePy

Tags: python, moviepy

I am attempting to concatenate edited video clips into a final movie video. The goal is to make small edits with the Streamer's name on each clip and overlay that text over each clip, then concatenate them into one final video.
Here is my code below:

```
PATH_TO_VALID_CLIPS = 'VideoCompilation/ClipData/valid_clips.txt'
PATH_TO_RAW_CLIPS = 'VideoCompilation\VideoFiles\\raw_clips'
FONT_PATH = 'E:\Projects\TwitchMontage\VideoCompilation\Fonts\Twitchy.TV Font\Twitchy.TV.ttf'
def read_valid_clips_list():
    #read valid clips
    file = open(PATH_TO_VALID_CLIPS, 'r')
    list = file.readlines()
    return list
    
def get_clip_data(filename):
    file = open('VideoCompilation\ClipData\clips_data.json')
    clips_data = json.load(file)

    return clips_data[filename]

def create_clips(list):
    clips = []
    for filename in list:
        filename = filename.strip()
        video_file_path = os.path.join(PATH_TO_RAW_CLIPS, filename)

        clip = VideoFileClip(video_file_path)
        clip = clip.fx(vfx.fadein, .1).fx(vfx.fadeout, .15)
        clip = add_text_overlay(clip, filename)

        clips.append(clip)

    return clips

def create_draft(clips):
    draft = concatenate_videoclips(clips, method='compose')
    draft.write_videofile("VideoCompilation/VideoFiles/videos/draft.mp4")
    return draft

def add_text_overlay(clip, file):
    clip_data = get_clip_data(file)
    streamerName = str(clip_data.get('streamerName'))

    text_clip = TextClip(txt = streamerName, size = (400,0), color = (145, 70, 255))
    tc_width, tc_height = text_clip.size

    text_clip = text_clip.set_position(0, tc_height)
    text_clip = text_clip.set_duration(2)                      
    clip = CompositeVideoClip([clip, text_clip])       
    return clip

def create_movie():
    list = read_valid_clips_list()
    clips = create_clips(list)
    draft = create_draft(clips)

    return draft

movie = create_movie()
```

This is the error traceback.

I do not understand where this error comes from at all.

```
[Running] python -u "e:\Projects\TwitchMontage\VideoCompilation\src\create_video.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Projects\TwitchMontage\VideoCompilation\src\create_video.py", line 60, in <module>
    movie = create_movie()
  File "e:\Projects\TwitchMontage\VideoCompilation\src\create_video.py", line 55, in create_movie
    clips = create_clips(list)
  File "e:\Projects\TwitchMontage\VideoCompilation\src\create_video.py", line 30, in create_clips
    clip = add_text_overlay(clip, filename)
  File "e:\Projects\TwitchMontage\VideoCompilation\src\create_video.py", line 45, in add_text_overlay
    text_clip = TextClip(txt = "streamerName", size = (400,0), color = (145, 70, 255))
  File "C:\Users\Alejandro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\VideoClip.py", line 1137, in __init__
    subprocess_call(cmd, logger=None)
  File "C:\Users\Alejandro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\moviepy\tools.py", line 46, in subprocess_call
    proc = sp.Popen(cmd, **popen_params)
  File "C:\Users\Alejandro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\Alejandro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 1247, in _execute_child
    args = list2cmdline(args)
  File "C:\Users\Alejandro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 549, in list2cmdline
    for arg in map(os.fsdecode, seq):
  File "C:\Users\Alejandro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\os.py", line 816, in fsdecode
    filename = fspath(filename)  # Does type-checking of `filename`.
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple
```

Comment: According to the `moviepy` installation instructions, on Windows you would have needed to edit a config file to specify an `IMAGEMAGICK_BINARY` string, pointing to where that utility is located on your system.  Apparently you have a trailing comma on that value, making it a tuple instead of a string.

Comment: Currently I have this done correctly, inside the config_defaults.py I have IMAGEMAGICK_BINARY = "D:\ImageMagick-7.1.0-Q16-HDRI\convert.exe"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [MoviePy Docs](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/), it looks like the `color` argument in [`TextClip`](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/ref/VideoClip/VideoClip.html?highlight=textclip#moviepy.video.VideoClip.TextClip) should be a string rather than an RGB tuple

Comment: This was the problem, thanks. It seems ColorClip object is allowed to have an RGB tuple but TextClip cannot.